# Python import from script outside package

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

Python unable to import package, but works correctly from within the package. A fully functional example below. In the virtual env I am using 3.6 All responses greatly appreciated!

```
parsers/
    __init__.py
    element.py
    parser1.py
    parser2.py
    parserresolver.py
outsidepkg.py
```

**init**.py is empty

element.py:

```
def router():
    pass
```

parser1.py:

```
from element import *
def parse(data):
    return data
```

parser2.py:

```
from element import *
def parse(data):
    return data
```

parserresolver.py:

```
import sys
from parser1 import *
from parser2 import *

def resolve(data):
    parseddata = None
    parsers = ['parser1', 'parser2'] 
    funcname = 'parse'
    for parser in parsers:
        module = sys.modules[parser]
        if hasattr(module, funcname):
            func = getattr(module, funcname)
            parseddata = func(data)
            print(parseddata)
            return parseddata

if __name__ == "__main__":
    resolve('something')
```

outsidepkg.py:

```
import parsers.parserresolver
def getapi(data):
    parsers.parserresolver.resolve(data)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(getapi('in parse api main'))
```

So when I call parserresolver.py directly it works great, no import errors and prints out "something" as expected.

But when I call outsidepkg.py I am getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\code\TestImport\TestImport\outsidepkg.py", line 1, in <module>
    import parsers.parserresolver
  File "C:\code\TestImport\TestImport\parsers\parserresolver.py", line 2, in <module>
    from parser1 import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'parser1'
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: `from .parser1 import *`

Comment: Thank you!! [Mad Physicist](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2988730/mad-physicist) and [U9](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8708364/u9-forward)
Very interesting. Adding the dot to do relative import got me further. Now it fails on `module = sys.modules[parser]` with `KeyError: 'parser1'` Curiously if I open up a interactive prompt and import sys I can see the qualified names parsers.parser1, but in the script sys.modules does not have any reference to parser1, name qualified or not. Should I be manually adding them to sys.modules? that seems fragile!

Comment: Seems like you need to ask another question. Ping us when you do.

Comment: I agree with you MP!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change the imports of:

```
from file import whatever
```

To:

```
from .file import whatever
```

Since your code to run it is outside the folder, use a `.` to get the directory, since the file isn't outside the package.

Comment: Marking this as answered as this solved the original problem I reported. Also special thanks to 
[Mad Physicist](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2988730/mad-physicist) who also came up with the same answer in the comment to original post.